# How to save the radio button value

Tags: jquery, html

How can I save the value of the radio buttons. A friend have made this to get a cookie.
Now I need to go to the next step, but I don't know how.

function saveForm(nForm){

```
var nFields = nForm.length;
for (i=0; i<nFields; i++)
  {
   var isType = nForm[i].type;
   alert(isType);
   if (isType == 'radio'){alert('Field '+ i+ ' is a radio button')}
   if (isType == 'select-one'){alert('Field '+i + ' is a select list')}
  }
```

}

```
    <form onsubmit="return saveForm(this)">
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="0">
      0 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="1">
      1 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="2">
      2 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="3">
      3 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="4">
      4 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="5">
      5 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="6">
      6 </input>
      <input type = "radio" name = "staande_houding_globaal" value="7">
      7 </input>
      <input type="button" value="Volgende" onClick="history.forward()","saveState()" class = "volgende" />
    </form>
```

Comment: not 100% clear what objective is

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of radio button try

```
$("input:radio[name=staande_houding_globaal]").click(function() {
alert($(this).val());
});
```

**OR**

```
 var xyz = $("input[name=staande_houding_globaal]:checked").val();
 console.log(xyz);
```

**Use this to check if the radio button is checked or not**

```
$('input[name=staande_houding_globaal]').is(":checked");
```

This will return a Boolean Value